# lightning component tab doe not work

Tags: lightning

1. Im trying to open the lead component in subtab but it does not work. can someone help here?

````
{
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getLeadId(component);
        helper.getLeadRecId(component);
    },
 newLeadClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.openTab({
         recordId: component.get("v.showRecord"),
         focus: true
        }).then(function(response) {
            workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
                parentTabId: response,
                recordId: '012800000012345678', //LEAD RECORD ID 
                focus: true
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log( 'Error is ' + error );
        });
       
    },
    ```

apex class

    @AuraEnabled
    public static boolean attachToTranscript(String ldId, String transcriptId) {
        try{
            LiveChatTranscript traObj = new LiveChatTranscript();
            traObj.id = transcriptId;
            traObj.Lead__c = ldId;
            traObj.LeadId = ldId;
            update traObj;
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new AuraHandledException('Error in updating transcript');
        }
    }
````

Comment: Neither of the Ids in your code is a Lead Id. Is this the actual code you are running? What does the console log say?

Comment: Thanks for responding David. line 9 has the lead record id" recordId: '012800000012345678',"   There's no error on console. Lead button doesn't open on click.

Comment: I modified the line 4 newLeadClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        recordId: component.set("v.showRecord"),

Comment: That is not a Lead Id. 012 is the key prefix for a Record Type. Lead Ids start with 00Q.

Comment: I updated my code above. Can you please tell me where should I be using lead Id?

Answer (score 0):

```
recordId: '012800000012345678', //LEAD RECORD ID
```

This simply isn't a Lead Id. This is a Record Type Id. Lead Ids start with `00Q`. But presumably you have a Lead Id stored somewhere in your component attributes - it does not make sense to hard-code it.

```
recordId: component.get("v.showRecord"),
```

It's not clear from the posted code what type the value of `v.showRecord` is. It will certainly need to be a valid sObject Id, not an object or some other value.

You can and should verify the values of your component attributes through, for example, `console.log()` statements. Your code will not work if you do not have the correct data and correct types present.